# Unable to run dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"project-key" /d:sonar.login="<token>"

Tags: sonarqube

Following [SonarScanner for .NET documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/), I have already installed SonarScanner / SonarQube locally and I can start the service at http://localhost:9000/

I have also run this command: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner`

But when I run dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"Project_Scan_1", I got this error

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
> Possible reasons for this include:
>
> - You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
> - You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-sonarscanner does not exist.
> - You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the command prompt as administrator, I could run the command.